# My laptop's Wi-Fi Internet won't work after a hard shutdown

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, internet-connection, toshiba-laptop, wifi-configuration

I have a Toshiba Satellite C850D laptop running Windows 10. Recently, it wouldn’t come on when I woke it from Sleep mode (it does this occasionally because it’s a little old), so I did a hard power down and turned it back on.

Once it came back on, the Internet wouldn’t work. I’ve tried both wired and wireless Internet connections, and neither one will work. In both cases, the Network and Sharing Center shows the connection and says “Identifying - No Internet Access.” I’ve been running Windows 10 for a month with no problem, so I don’t think it's an OS compatibility problem.

I’m not really sure what to do because most of the usual fixes for computer problems that I can think of require an Internet connection (e.g. reinstalling drivers).

EDIT: Running a TCP/IP reset fixed it temporarily, but when I brought it out of sleep mode today the Internet wasn't working again. I tried another TCP/IP reset, but it didn't work this time. I've also run a chkdsk and sfc /scannow in elevated cmd, but both came back with no problems found.

Comment: Did you do a restart after the hard shutdown and Windows loaded?

Comment: I added my computer's exact model. However, I don't believe it is a Windows 10 compatibility issue because I've been using Windows 10 for over a month without having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a Full shutdown/reboot after the abend?

I typically like to run chkdsk after an abnormal shutdown; in windows 10 you can schedule a boot time check disk from the command line with a switch.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry, I end up doing a fair amount of support for computer/laptop users, and troubleshooting typically requires a dialog.
Users don't always understand that logging off and logging back in are not good enough for many issues, and that they require a reboot. Windows ten makes it trickier to do an "offline" disk check.

Answer (score 0):

If all the lights come on and drivers are all ok and in device manager everything working ok. I would suggest repair system files. Or resetting the TCP/IP stack.

System check: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/929833

TCP/IP: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/299357

Comment: TCP/IP reset did it for me. It's still got a caution symbol beside the Ethernet icon on the taskbar and it constantly says "Identifying," but the Internet works so I guess it's okay. Thanks.

Comment: Whoops, turns out TCP/IP reset was just a temporary fix. I'm going to edit the original post to include everything up to where I am now.

Comment: Try uninstalling your drivers for your network card. Then re install. See if that works.